# Playwright C# - wait for input text to be empty

Tags: c#, .net, playwright

I'm writing a test using Playwright with C# bindings, and I came across a problem with waiting for element input to have no text.
Before "add" action, input fields look like this:

[image]

Article Number input has id="Number", and Name has id="Name" - just to be clear.
After "add" action, input fields are cleared of text:

[image]

it's a matter of split second for inputs to be cleared of text, but Playwright doesn't wait for it and starts typing before clearing inputs, which messes up my test.

I've tried to use:

```
await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("#Number >> text=");
await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("#Name>> text=");
```

but it didn't help out.
How to wait for text to be empty?

Answer (score 2):

I think your selector is asking Playwright to find an Element with no text. Input Elements store their contents in their Value attribute, so actually always have no text!

You can use [this](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page#page-input-value) method to check an Input Elements value against a page object, or [this](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-input-value) method against an IElementHandle.
Maybe have a utility method, something like:

```
string inputValue = "input";
DateTime timeout = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
while(timeout > DateTime.Now && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputValue)){
   inputValue = await page.InputValueAsync("#Number");
}
```

This will wait for the Input Element to have an empty value.

There is some caveats: Text= does check the value attributes on Input elements of type button & submit, as explained [here](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/selectors#:%7E:text=Input%20elements%20of%20the%20type).

Answer (score 1):

This may not have been available when the question was asked.

You can now do:

```
await Expect(page.Locator("#Number")).ToHaveValueAsync("");
```

Comment: For me, Assertions.Expect worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else is looking for an answer to the same problem, [Page.WaitForFunctionAsync(expression, arg, options)](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page/#page-wait-for-function) looks like the ideal way to wait for an element to be empty. The nice thing compared to the before mentioned solution is that it requires less code, the waiting is non busy, and there is less communication between client and browser, because the polling (until ready or timeout) happens inside the browser itself.

You can pass it the JavaScript expression (which will be executed in the browser), for example `textBox => textBox.value == ''`
And in the second parameter you can pass it the element handle of the textBox.

(I didn't try this myself because I'm normally using PlayWright with NodeJS, but I think with these hints you'll get a long way.)